# How to access files in another partition using another linux OS

Tags: debian, permissions, root

I cannot log into my Debian Bullseye/sid OS and all my files are on there. So I created a bootable USB for Ubuntu and I want to access my files but it says "permission denied".

**Is there a way I can access my files? I know the user name and password of the original account that is blocked.**

I can see the folder with all my data here (picture shown), and I can also see, by navigating from the GRUB menu on startup that all my files are still there.

[image]

Comment: Of course your files are present. Now it might be due to a mount error, you should try to mount with proper FS & read permissions from the shell to debug that. (you will need root permissions)

Comment: Can you direct me on how to do that or to a place that gives you instructions on how to do that? Actually, when I do boot up normally, it says "Load Kernel Failed" but it still continues until the login screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is some type of permissions issue with your mount. I'm assuming the partition of your old drive you want to access is /dev/sdb1. You could do:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

Then do:

```
cd /mnt
```

You should be able to browse the files

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked.